# How to download Google Street View images at different time period

Tags: javascript, python

Google Launched time capsule in Google Street View. Google Street View image API ([Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro))is used to download GSV static images, but those images have no time information. I am wondering it is possible to use APIs to download the GSV images at different time periods.

Comment: I am not trying to create a Google Street View on other website. Actually, all I want is to collect the GSV static images at different time period for my research project, http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1618866715000874 I hope to collect GSV images at different time periods for this kind of studies, I am wondering if that possible.